# New bike is making rattling noise

Tags: chain, derailleur, derailleur-rear

Brand new specialized rockhopper 2022 is making rattling noise.

**Sample:**

Is this normal or could it be a manufacturing defect?

Comment: Can't really tell from the video what's going on sorry.  If the bike is brand new, then its under warranty so take it back for service.  You might get a better view by getting the bike off the ground and hand-pedalling it rather than on the road.

Comment: Can you confirm whether you can get this noise when you rotate the pedals slowly when you are off the bike.  There's a few steps to trying to figure out an unexpected noise.  Does it only happen when you are on the bike.  Does it only happen when you are pedaling.  Does it only happen when you are seated/out of the saddle.  Does it only happen in some gears but not others.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The noise happens every time your foot is in the same point of rotating the pedal. It sounds to me like the chain is catching on the front derailleur once per rotation. Not unusual and not difficult to fix, perhaps the cable has lost a little tension as can happen. It might be caused by flex as you pedal while the derailleur is a hair too close to the chain in top gear.

As it's a new bike, the shop will be happy to take a little look over the bike and correct noises like this, just make sure you point it out to them. This is why it's common for a shop to offer a brief tune up after about six weeks for new bike sales. I wouldn't call it a manufacturing defect unless one of the chainring teeth was bent before you had it, rather it's a minor misalignment that can be corrected quite readily.

Comment: It turned out to be the exact same thing that you suggested. They re-tuned it and now it's working great. Thank you